# How do we add custom properties to a google drive file(PDF) using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

```
function addCustomProperty(fileId) { 
  var property =  {
                    key: 'department', 
                    value: 'Sales', 
                    visibility: 'PUBLIC' 
                  }; 

  Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
}
```

How do we add the custom properties to a specific file in Google Drive using Apps Script?

Comment: Your code works fine for me and I can insert properties to the files. What are you trying to do? What is your problem? Is this code not working?

Comment: Error i m facing is : [Response code :404 , Message : Not Found.(line 7, file"propertyadd") ]

Comment: Have you enabled [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)? 
Check if you can get the file through the API [Try it](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix=true) section to confirm that you are using the correct file ID

Comment: I am getting this response. where to include file id in the appscript file to add custom properties to specific file{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1-XjO4NLX9p1ae8P7eG7Dd9rOW7TZEKLc",
 "name": "inheritance.py",
 "mimeType": "text/x-python"
}

Comment: So you can get the file, how are you executing your Apps Script? Have you enabled Drive in `Advanced Google Services`?

Comment: Hey thankyou found the solution.

Comment: Could you please post it so other people having the same problem can see your solution?

Comment: The OP probably didn't Drive API enabled.